# Test file existence with exit status from gnu-find

Tags: bash, find, file-exists

When `test -e file` is not flexible enough, I tend to use the following Bash idiom to check the existence of a file:

```
if [ -n "$(find ${FIND_ARGS} -print -quit)" ] ; then
   echo "pass"
else
   echo "fail"
fi
```

But since I am only interested in a boolean value, are there any `${FIND_ARGS}` that will let me do instead:

```
if find ${FIND_ARGS} ; ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say no. `man find`...

> find exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur.   This is deliberately a very broad description, but if the return value is non-zero, you should not rely on the correctness of the results of find.

Testing for output is probably fine for find. That isn't a "Bash idiom". If that's not good enough and you have Bash available then you can use *extglobs* and possibly *globstar* for file matching tests with `[[`. Find should only be used for complex recursive file matching, or actual searching for files, and other things that can't easily be done with Bash features.